# finding the context node, what value is it supposed to be

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to work with a template that I created and am now calling inside of another template.

Call the formatHole template using the value of the context
node for the holeScore parameter, and for the parScore parameter use the value of
the par element whose holeNumber attribute equals the holeNum variable.

Here is the formatHole template

```
            <xsl:template name="formatHole">
                <xsl:param name="parScore"  />
                <xsl:param name="holeScore" />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@holeScore &lt; @parScore" >
                            <td class="low"><xsl:value-of select="@holeScore" /></td>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="@holeScore > @parScore" >
                            <td class="high"><xsl:value-of select="@holeScore" /></td>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@holeScore" /></td>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:template>
```

Then here is the template for score that calls the formatHole template

```
        <xsl:template match="score">
            <!-- <xsl:variable name="holeScore" select="." />  -->
            <xsl:variable name="holeNum" select="@holeNumber" /> 

                <xsl:call-template name="formatHole">
                    <xsl:with-param name="holeScore" select="context()" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="parScore" select="tournament/course/par[@holeNumber = $holeNum]" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@holeNumber"/></td>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@holeNum=18" >
                    <td class="sub"><xsl:value-of select="sum(//score[@holeNumber > 9 and @holeNumber &lt; 18])" /></td>
                    <td class="final"><xsl:value-of select="sum(//score[@holeNumber])" /></td>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@holeNum=9">
                    <td class="sub"><xsl:value-of select="sum(//score[@holeNumber &lt;= 9])" /></td>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </tr>
        </xsl:template>
```

The scores are not coming out like they should, only every other hole has a value really.

The XML looks like this

```
    <name>Westfield Open</name>
    <date>5/28/2008 - 5/31/2008</date>
    <location>Westfield Golf Club</location>

    <course>
       <par holeNumber="1">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="2">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="3">5</par>
       <par holeNumber="4">3</par>
       <par holeNumber="5">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="6">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="7">5</par>
       <par holeNumber="8">3</par>
       <par holeNumber="9">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="10">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="11">5</par>
       <par holeNumber="12">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="13">3</par>
       <par holeNumber="14">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="15">5</par>
       <par holeNumber="16">4</par>
       <par holeNumber="17">3</par>
       <par holeNumber="18">4</par>
    </course>

    <golfer>
       <name>Brett Bierson</name>
       <round roundNumber="1">
          <score holeNumber="1">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="2">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="3">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="4">2</score>
          <score holeNumber="5">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="6">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="7">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="8">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="9">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="10">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="11">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="12">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="13">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="14">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="15">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="16">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="17">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="18">3</score>
       </round>
       <round roundNumber="2">
          <score holeNumber="1">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="2">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="3">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="4">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="5">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="6">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="7">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="8">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="9">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="10">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="11">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="12">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="13">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="14">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="15">6</score>
          <score holeNumber="16">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="17">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="18">4</score>
       </round>
       <round roundNumber="3">
          <score holeNumber="1">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="2">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="3">6</score>
          <score holeNumber="4">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="5">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="6">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="7">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="8">2</score>
          <score holeNumber="9">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="10">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="11">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="12">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="13">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="14">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="15">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="16">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="17">2</score>
          <score holeNumber="18">4</score>
       </round>
       <round roundNumber="4">
          <score holeNumber="1">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="2">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="3">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="4">2</score>
          <score holeNumber="5">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="6">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="7">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="8">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="9">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="10">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="11">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="12">4</score>
          <score holeNumber="13">6</score>
          <score holeNumber="14">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="15">5</score>
          <score holeNumber="16">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="17">3</score>
          <score holeNumber="18">4</score>
       </round>
    </golfer>

    </tournament>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a number of problems in your XSLT. Firstly in your named template **formatHole**. You have two parameters, **holeScore** and **parScore**, but to reference these you need to be doing **$holeScore**, not **@holeScore**. By doing **@holeScore** you are looking for an attribute named **holeScore** on whatever the current context node is (Still **score** in this case). Parameters (and variables) in templates are referenced using the **$** sign.

The template should look like this

```
       <xsl:template name="formatHole">
            <xsl:param name="parScore"  />
            <xsl:param name="holeScore" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$holeScore &lt; $parScore" >
                        <td class="low"><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$holeScore > $parScore" >
                        <td class="high"><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```

Or maybe, to avoid some repetition, like this...

```
       <xsl:template name="formatHole">
            <xsl:param name="parScore"  />
            <xsl:param name="holeScore" />
            <td>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$holeScore &lt; $parScore" >
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">low</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$holeScore > $parScore" >
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">high</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" />
             </td>
        </xsl:template>
```

Secondly (and thirdly), there are issues with how you call the template

```
<xsl:call-template name="formatHole">
   <xsl:with-param name="holeScore" select="context()" />
   <xsl:with-param name="parScore" select="tournament/course/par[@holeNumber = $holeNum]" />
 </xsl:call-template>
```

**context()** is not (as far as I am aware) a valid keyword. It should be **current()**.

Also, the xpath for the **parScore** will be relative to the current **score** element, so you are looking for a child element called **tournament**. Really you should be using an 'absolute' path, from the document node. like so:

```
<xsl:call-template name="formatHole">
   <xsl:with-param name="holeScore" select="current()" />
   <xsl:with-param name="parScore" select="/tournament/course/par[@holeNumber = $holeNum]" />
 </xsl:call-template>
```

Actually, it may be more efficient to use a key to look up the par scores

```
<xsl:key name="par" match="course/par" use="@holeNumber" />
```

Then you could do this

```
<xsl:call-template name="formatHole">
   <xsl:with-param name="holeScore" select="current()" />
   <xsl:with-param name="parScore" select="key('par', $holeNum)" />
 </xsl:call-template>
```

Finally, there is an issue with how you calculate the **sub** and **final** scores

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//score[@holeNumber &lt;= 9])" />
```

This is an absolute expression, and so will add up scores for all rounds, not just the current round. The expression should probably look like this, which will find all the **score** elements for the current parent element.

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(../score[@holeNumber &lt;= 9])" />
```

Also note that your **xsl:choose** that checks whether the hole number is 9 or 18 should be one of the following

```
<xsl:when test="@holeNumber=18" >

or

<xsl:when test="$holeNum=18" >
```

(The variable **holeNum** is set to the value of attribute **holeNumber** so both are the same)

Try fixing all these issues, and see how you get on.....

Comment: Thank you, that helped get the information into the scores column, they are the same values for all 4 rounds though.  I will work on this more tonight.

Comment: That almost did it but for some reason I am having trouble displaying the score relative to par below the par line and the players score line.  I have the first 3 holes but it stops there.  I have revised the code above